# Convert all C# scripts to dll in unity project automatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, class-library

I have a pretty large project where different scripts are available and attached with different game objects in the hierarchy. Now I want to make dll of all files. I found [**unity official guide**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html) that involves lots of steps that I have to repeat for every script. Not only this but I have also attached each dll to gameobject again then, need to remove the same script whose dll i have converted. And if there any setting on the inspector i have to follow again. My question is that is this the only way to do this job? Is there any automatic way available? that convert all my scripts into dll? within unity ?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to split all stable and reusable code into unity packages or at least into separate folders where you can create assembly definitions files so all scripts inside won't compile every time you change something in a different place. Start here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html